# Socket.on is not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, mern

I am building a message board as a learning exercise and have working notifications and a chat app working with socket.io.

I am trying to integrate a basic video call functionality, but I am stumped on some basic preparations for that feature. My socket.on code isn't firing when the server emits the relevant function and I have no clue why. The console logs around the emits are all executing, so I know the code is being reached.

On the client my socket.on code is in the same component as my notifications and they are working and it is definitely mounted.

It's the userOff and receiveCall functions that aren't being executed (for whatever reason)...

Any help will be appreciated.

Server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('messageFromServer');
  socket.on('messageToServer', (dataFromClient) => {
    connectedUsers[dataFromClient.username] = socket;
  });
  socket.on('join', ({ username, room }) => {
    socket.join(room);
    socket.emit('message', 'Welcome!');
    socket.broadcast
      .to(room)
      .emit('message', `${username} has joined the room!`);
  });
  socket.on('messageRoom', ({ username, room, message }) => {
    socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('message', `${username}: ${message}`);
  });
  socket.on('call', ({ username, id }) => {
    if (connectedUsers[username]) {
      connectedUsers[username].emit('recieveCall', id);
      console.log('online emitted');
    } else {
      socket.emit('userOff');
      console.log('offline emitted');
    }
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.disconnect(true);
  });
});
```

client:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import StateContext from '../StateContext';
import DispatchContext from '../DispatchContext';
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:5000';

const Socket = () => {
  const appState = useContext(StateContext);
  const appDispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);
  const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('messageFromServer', () => {
      socket.emit('messageToServer', { username: appState.username });
    });
    socket.on('userOff', () => {
      console.log('user offline');
    });
    socket.on('recieveCall', (id) => {
      console.log('recieve call');
    });
    socket.on('mailNotification', () => {
      document.getElementById('notifyMail').classList.add('notify');
    });
    socket.on('boardsNotification', () => {
      document.getElementById('notifyBoards').classList.add('notify');
    });
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default Socket;
```

Comment: Your component will initialize a new socket every time it re-renders, which will e.g. happen whenever anything in the context changes. You should do it either in a `useEffect` or entirely outside of the component. But it's unlikely that this is the issue why you don't see any console logs. Did you verify that the client socket did properly connect?

Comment: do what in a useeffect? Yes I don't see console logs on the client. It's surely connected as the notifications are functioning correctly

Comment: You should not initialize the socket (`const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);`) in the component because every time the component re-renders it will create a new socket.

Comment: okay, so how do I access it?

Comment: You access it the same way just pull its instanciation out of the component.

Comment: const socket = ?

Comment: Just take the line and pull it out of the component definition. You could also put it in an extra js file and export it. You don't need to do anything different or extra. Just pull it out of the component. You are aware that components re-render which means the code inside of it will be executed again?

Comment: yes ofc I'm aware of something so basic... I have no idea where you want me to set up the connection, if not in a react component.

Comment: If you are aware of that then you should also be aware that every time `Socket` re-renders it will instanciate a new socket object by calling `socketIOClient(endpoint)`. You actually don't use those socket objects anywhere because the function inside `useEffect` is a closure that got created on mount and still only sees the first socket object that got created. But as that is totally unnecessary you should instanciate the socket OUTSIDE of the component. It doesn't matter where you put it, as long as it is not inside of the `Socket` component.

Comment: the whole point of the socket.io-client library is that it was designed to be used in react components.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `socket.io` existed before react and wasn't designed for react at all you simply don't get what I'm trying to relay to you. You can use the socket just fine inside the component. But you shouldn't initialize it inside of the component. Are you lacking the very basic programming terminology because it should be crystal clear by now what I mean. I'm not telling you to not use it together with react. It will work just fine. Simply do not call `socketIOClient(endpoint)` where you are currently doing it but outside of your `Socket`. What is so hard to understand about that?

Comment: You are creating a new socket instance on every render. Don't do that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222376/discussion-between-trixn-and-harry-young).

Comment: So I can put it with the imports?

Comment: I put it with the imports and exported it, which I think is what you were suggesting. Aaand it's working better, now, so thanks.

Comment: Glad that it helped. And sorry for my rough comment I was a little bit impatient.

Answer (score -2):

did you try call socket.open first

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socketopen

and listen the connect event

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99

Comment: I know that the socket's open as I just used it to emit the call event to the server...? Or am I being silly here??

Comment: Sorry, I finally figure out what you asking for,  
I have a question about did you send "call" event from the client?  
I don't see any "call" event emit in the client code.  
or even trigger from server itself

Comment: call event is being fired by a different component

Comment: did the server "call" event callback trigger?

Comment: Can I asking the emit "call" event part, I assume you use "call" event to deal with online or offline.
But this maybe have some issue, if you emit the "call" event before the "connect" event fire,
the if connection lose there are no way to trigger the "call" event from the client,
there why socket.io provide Event: ‘connect’ and Event: ‘disconnect’

Comment: the normal way when server duel with incoming connection, which can check https://gist.github.com/luciopaiva/e6f60bd6e156714f0c5505c2be8e06d8

we will listen "disconnect" event on every incoming connection.